# integral cohomology groups of an aspherical manifold are isomorphic to the integral cohomology groups of it's fundemental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

(of corresponding dimensions). how can I prove this?   I think my main stumbling block is my general ignorance of group cohomology.

Comment: To answer this, we need to know what is your definition of group cohomology.

Comment: I have only learned the definition contained in Dummit and Foote wherein it is defined to be $Ext_{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$.  Are there non-equivalent definitions?

Comment: All definitions are equivalent, but to prove something is equivalent to one of them you need to actually pick one of them!

Comment: By the way, it is usually best if the body of the question is self contained and, in particular, does not require the title to make sense (your titiel/question does not satisfy this condition): have you ever seen a book whose first sentence starts in the cover?

Comment: agreed!  though I'm willing to work out the equivalence between your definition and mine if yours lends itself to a proof of the statement.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $X$ is an aspherical CW-complex (for example, an anspherical smooth manifold), so that the universal covering space $\tilde X$ is contractible (an allow me to be sloppy with basepoints...)

The group $G=\pi_1(X)$ acts properly discontinuously on $\tilde X$, and this action induces an action of $G$ on the singular complex $C_\bullet(\tilde X)$, so that this complex can be seen as a complex of $G$-modules. Since $\tilde X$ is contractible, the homology of the complex $C_\bullet(\tilde X)$ is zero in all non-zero degrees, and isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ in degree zero—a tiny bit of care will show that the homology in degree zero is in fact a *trivial* $G$-module.

Now, a little fiddling with definitions will show that

> **Lemma.** for each $p$, the group of $p$-chains $C_p(\tilde X)$ is a *free* $G$-module.

In fact, that fiddling will show

> **Porism.** a basis of $C_p(\tilde X)$ as a $G$-module can be identified with the set of singular $p$-simplices in $X$.

It follows that $C_\bullet(\tilde X)$ is in fact a free resolution of the trivial  $G$-module $\mathbb Z$. The general nonsense that goes under the name of homological algebra tells us now that we can compute $H^\bullet(G,\mathbb Z)=\mathrm{Ext}_{\mathbb ZG}^\bullet(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z)$ as the cohomology of the complex $\hom_{\mathbb ZG}(C_\bullet(\tilde X),\mathbb Z)$. Now, the porism above (and a similar observation regarding differentials...) allows us to identify the complex $\hom_{\mathbb ZG}(C_\bullet(\tilde X),\mathbb Z)$ with the slightly simpler $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(C_\bullet(X),\mathbb Z)$.

Finally, the cohomology of the complex $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(C_\bullet(X),\mathbb Z)$ is, by definition, the integral singular cohomology of the space $X$.

More details can be found in MacLane's *Homology* book, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Mariano. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One has in general $H^*(BG;\mathbb Z)\cong H^*(G;\mathbb Z)$ where the left hand side is singular cohomology, and the right hand side is group cohomology.  In the case at hand, $H^*(\pi_1(X);\mathbb Z)\cong H^*(B\pi_1(X);\mathbb Z)$.  However, $B\pi_1(X)$ is a $K(\pi_1(X),1)$ space, and so is $X$ since it's aspherical.  Since $X$ is a CW complex (it's a manifold) and CW Eilenberg-Maclane spaces are unique up to weak homotopy equivalence, this means that $X$ is weak homotopy equivalent to $K(\pi_1(X),1)=B\pi_1(X)$.  Since cohomology is weak homotopy invariant, this gives us the result.

Comment: thank you. what is meant by "BG"?

Comment: The space $BG$ is the [classifying space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) of $G$.  For a discrete group (i.e., not a topological group), $BG$ will be a $K(G,1)$ space.

Comment: great. thanks very much.